# API for option contract tickers

Tags: options, programming

Is there some API I can use to get a list of all available option contract tickers on some underlying? I'm using thinkorswim for data, but there is no way to get the tickers via the COM object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interactive Brokers API allows to pull option chain: https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/options.html#option_chains&gsc.tab=0

Answer (score 1):

Bloomberg also let you get the option chain via their API (not free). field is called `OPT_CHAIN`